# Secure file storage in a server

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I have a job website, so there are number of cv's uploaded to the server and stored in a folder location which is public. i am just wondering what the security measures i can do in the Apache, php level to stop unauthorised people accessing other peoples cv's

i have

1. disabled directory browsing
2. created false links in html which then maps in .htaccess to a another location

..etc

just wondering is there a way we can completely hide the file name appear in the browser url (may be with a header like application/pdf ..etc and read the content of the file on the fly) is this possible or is there a better way like store them in the MySQL DB ?

Comment: Don't put the uploaded files inside your www root folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the files outside of the document root (so your server won't by default map a URL to it) and use a script that confirms an authenticated user and then streams the resume's contents to that user only.

For example...

```
<?php

session_start();

include 'app.php';

$userAuthenticated = (new Auth)->check($_SESSION['username']);

$file = isset($_GET['file']) ? 
        $_GET['file'] :
        FALSE;

$file = FILES_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . preg_replace('/[^\w.]/', '', $file);

if ($userAuthenticated AND file_exists($file)) {
    readfile($file);
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    echo 'You\'re not authenticated!';
}
```

This code should give you the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

Never allow user-uploaded files in the docroot.  This is very insecure, as you are hosting content provided by others.

Never allow user-uploaded files to be stored with names provided by the user.  Imagine if someone uploads somescript.php, and you name it as such and keep it within your docroot.  It can be executed by anyone.

Store files outside of the docroot, keep the details of the files (original name, mime type, etc.) in a database, and access them with a script, using `readfile()` or similar.  Only allow access to these files to those who are supposed to have access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess rewrite.

In php use headers and readfile() function, change and store the file id in a mysql db, and then make sure to deny from all in .htaccess for the upload directory.